# Does something like HTTP_GET_RESPONSE exist?

Tags: php, get, response

I was curious about getting the result of this  http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=141.100.10.49 (Result = DE) into a variable i can use to write into my DB (last thing is easy for me but i am curious about getting an answer how to do the first thing. beneath the snippet i had in my mind :-)

```
    <?php
    $in = HTTP_GET_RESPONSE('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=141.100.10.49');
    echo $in;
    /*write to DB*/
    ?>
```

thanks for the help in advance!

P.S.: I don't know much about java/python/C(+/++/#)

P.P.S.: http://kater.selfhost.me/stats/test.php that's the result :-(

Comment: file_get_contents(URL)

Comment: @Akam That would not get the full HTTP response...

Comment: @PeeHaa: he need just response body not HTTP response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is configured appropriately you can use:

```
 <?php
$in = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=141.100.10.49');
echo $in;
/*write to DB*/
?>
```

Just make sure you have `allow_url_fopen` set in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

It's called `file_get_contents`.

```
$in = file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=141.100.10.49');
```

In general, most of the file-related functions in PHP allow you to supply a URL, and they'll treat the remote document as if it were a file (unless this feature is disabled in your `php.ini`).

Comment: since i use a server on a hoster, there is no option i can control regarding the php.ini, but it seems to be working now, so i don't bother about it anymore ;-)